# SuiteScript; Asynchronous HTTP request inside of user event script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, netsuite, suitescript

#### Objective

I am working on a SuiteScript user event script in Netsuite that has to contact an external endpoint via HTTP request. Unfortunately it is possible that it could take a bit for the endpoint to respond. In an effort to minimize user inconvenience I am trying to find a way to execute this call asynchronously.

#### Issues

Unfortunately the nlapiRequestURL() method that is intended for HTTP requests only accepts a callback function for asynchronous use when the method is used within a client script.

#### Attempted So Far

I have looked into using a scheduled script which is what is recommended by Netsuite in these instances, however, the number of simultaneous instances of a scheduled script which can be queued at one time is limited by the number of manually created script deployments that are available. We're concerned about what might happen if the client runs a csv update that modifies thousands of records at one time.

Finally, I've tried just using a XMLHttpRequest, but that's not supported by SuiteScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlapiRequestURL()` is the only way to send HTTP request on the server side (i.e. user event in your case), `XMLHttpRequest` is not supported on server side.

On client side `nlapiRequestURL()` is a wrapper on `XMLHttpRequest` so, it allows a async callback.

Scheduled script makes the HTTP request async from the record creation/update process but, beware the `nlapiRequestURL` in scheduled script itself is not asynchronous.

> however, the number of simultaneous instances of a scheduled script
>   which can be queued at one time is limited by the number of manually
>   created script deployments that are available. We're concerned about
>   what might happen if the client runs a csv update that modifies
>   thousands of records at one time.

Firstly, no. of scheduled script that can run in parallel is always 1 in normal NetSuite accounts, even if you create thousands of deployments (it queues them, but, not essentially fire them immediately). If SuiteCloud Plus licenses are purchased it can go upto 15. Secondly, firing a different scheduled script for each record update is not advisable as you can potentially block other scheduled scripts from running, as you would have too many queued up scheduled scripts.

I would recommend EITHER use a flag (option1: company level script parameter which is updatable/accessible using `nlapiLoadConfiguration`/`nlapiSubmitConfiguration`, option2: using a custom record) and then schedule an another scheduled script that runs every few minutes to check flag and fires the `nlapiRequestURL` for recently created records,

OR

in the company level script parameter keep track of last run time, and pick all records in a search created after the last run, and fire `nalpiRequestURL` for them in your scheduled script, which is deployed to run every few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are considering an asynch call as being suitable for a User Event  script then I'm guessing you could set a flag (custom checkbox field) to indicate the record needs to update from the external source and defer the http call to a scheduled script. You could then then create a scheduled script that looks for flagged records and calls the external endpoint using nlapiRequestURL synchronously. The scheduled script can chug through the records and update them.

You can just make the scheduled script run frequently or trigger an instance from your user event script. Make sure you are calling nlapiScheduleScript with a deployment id as well as a script id.

If the user needs to know about success or failure of this call then move it client side. In your client event script create another flag and set that when you make the asynch call and reset it when the call returns. Your save page client script should return false when the client side flag is set so the user cannot submit the record until it's been updated.